# Reaching end of void function yield unexpected results

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program to manage a list of names (a segment of the program is below). I expected the function "choice()" to end and return to main()--and thus end the program--when the user's input for the variable "option" was 4. However, choice() tends to repeat a few times even after assigning 4 to "option", e.g:

```
Would you like to:
    (1) - Add name(s) to the list
    (2) - Remove name(s) from the list
    (3) - View the list
    (4) - Exit the program
(type 1, 2, 3, or 4): 4


Exiting Program...


Would you like to:
    (1) - Add name(s) to the list
    (2) - Remove name(s) from the list
    (3) - View the list
    (4) - Exit the program
(type 1, 2, 3, or 4): 4


Exiting Program...

ryan$ _
```

In the absence of the entire program, what do you think may be causing the problem? Sorry if there is not enough information to make a recommendation.

You can see I commented "exit(0)" from the end of the fourth if statement of choice()--in which choice() should reach its end and return to main(). I would prefer to avoid this statement but it is the only solution I can make work at the moment. Thanks for your help.

-Ryan

```
int main()
{
     cout << endl 
          << "WELCOME TO THE NAME LIST PROGRAM" << endl
          << "--------------------------------" << endl;

    choice();

    return 0;
}


void choice()
{
    string option = "0";

    cout << "\nWould you like to:"             << endl
     << "\t(1) - Add name(s) to the list"      << endl
     << "\t(2) - Remove name(s) from the list" << endl
     << "\t(3) - View the list"                << endl
     << "\t(4) - Exit the program"             << endl
     << "(type 1, 2, 3, or 4): ";

    getline(cin,option);

    while( option != "1" && option != "2" &&
           option != "3" && option != "4"  )
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid input, reenter: ";
        getline(cin,option);
    }

    if(option == "1")
    {
        appendNames();
        choice();
    }
    else if(option == "2")
    {
        string flag = "menu";
        removeNames(flag);
        choice();
    }

    else if(option == "3")
    {
        viewNames();
        choice();
    }

    else if(option == "4")
    {
        cout << "\n\nExiting Program...\n\n";
        // exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You did declare `choice()` before main executes right?

Comment: Yeah, I include a function prototype before main is called. The whole prog is ~480 lines so I only included what I thought was most pertinent.

Comment: I've just tested your posted code, I can't replicate the issue. What's your OS/compiler commands/execution commands?

Comment: An aside: the problem arises when the other options are called before the exit option is selected (i.e. view the list, remove a name, add a name, then try to exit). I am running mac os x compiling with gcc (or whatever the name is of the new compiler mac uses). My hunch is the intricacies of the other functions create the problem; applying the advice offered by Baltasarq below actually worked.

Comment: Oh. That aside is integral, because it means that @batasarq made valid points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from a misconception about a how a function works. Say that you have a function that shows your name:

```
void showName()
{
    cout << "Ryan" << endl;
}
```

Now say that you want to repeat that 10 times. In your particular way of programming, you probably would do something like:

```
void showName(int times)
{
    cout << "Ryan" << endl;

    if ( times > 0 ) {
        showName( --times );
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    showName( 10 );
}
```

This way of programming is known as recursion, but I am quite sure that you have reached that by chance. Recursion is handy in some situations, but it is not the common way of doing simple things, like repeating something. Let's see the actual program calling the function 10 times:

```
void showName()
{
    cout << "Ryan" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        showName();
    }
}
```

Each time you call the function `showName()`, the callee, it has to return to the caller. If you do what you have shown in your example:

```
if( option == "1" )
{
    appendNames();
    choice();
}
```

Then you are actually calling `choice()` as many times as the user has chosen any other option apart from 4 (exit). This explains why you have to call `exit( 0 )` in order to get an immediate effect.

Summarizing, your program should be:

```
int main()
{
     cout << endl 
          << "WELCOME TO THE NAME LIST PROGRAM" << endl
          << "--------------------------------" << endl;

    while( !choice() );

    return 0;
}


bool choice()
{
    bool toret = false;
    string option = "0";

    cout << "\nWould you like to:"             << endl
     << "\t(1) - Add name(s) to the list"      << endl
     << "\t(2) - Remove name(s) from the list" << endl
     << "\t(3) - View the list"                << endl
     << "\t(4) - Exit the program"             << endl
     << "(type 1, 2, 3, or 4): ";

    getline(cin,option);

    while( option != "1" && option != "2" &&
           option != "3" && option != "4"  )
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid input, reenter: ";
        getline(cin,option);
    }

    if(option == "1")
    {
        appendNames();
    }
    else if(option == "2")
    {
        removeNames();
    }

    else if(option == "3")
    {
        viewNames();
    }

    else if(option == "4")
    {
        cout << "\n\nExiting Program...\n\n";
        toret = true;
    }

    return toret;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an incorrect assessment: the recursion in his other cases has no effect on his quit case, which is what we are discussing here

Comment: Take into account he has not published the whole source code.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to this situation

Comment: Hey, yes: removing the recursion cleaned things up. The recursive structure was intentional, expect of course where I encountered the difficulty trying to terminate the program. I am still not exactly clear, however, why choice() is called again after 4 is assigned to option for the first time. I register it has something to do with the calling function stacking up calls to choice() but I do not comprehend this totally. Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated.

Comment: @lightandlight I thought on the same lines as you in regard to where the recursion was happening (i.e. without the "exit if statement") and couldn't see why it caused problems. Seeing all my source code would make it easier to assess the problem, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your while loop. The user will have to keep entering inputs until an invalid input it given.

```
while( option != "1" && option != "2" &&
       option != "3" && option != "4"  )
{
    cout << "\nInvalid input, reenter: ";
    getline(cin,option);
}
```

Changing the loop condition or moving everything within the loop should do the trick.
Hope that helps. :)

P.S: If you're moving everything within the While loop, make sure you add a `break;` for the exit option.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The loop condition checks for an invalid input, so the user has to keep entering a line until a valid input is given, unless I'm misreading (which is entirely possible).

Comment: @hvd I agree with you

Comment: I tend to agree with hvd. The while loop checks for invalid numbers/input. 4 is valid and will go through to the series of if statements. The key lays is simplifying my algorithm a bit, as per Baltasarq's suggestions.